# Show child QWidget out of parent QWidget area

Tags: qt, visibility, crop, qwidget

I've got QListWidget as a child inside QPlainTextEdit for purposes of completion suggestions.

Suggestion list is displayed under cursor and when line is almost full, part of list widget is cropped by the border of text edit. Is there any possibility to force child widget show out of parent widget region?

An idea I have, is to make the text and list edit elements "siblings", i. e. add them to the same parent. But this would require my event handling mechanism (as I suppose parent-child relation between those two elements).

I think there must be a way to achieve this, as I studied [Katepart component](http://kate-editor.org/about-katepart/) and there is KateCompletionWidget (displays suggestions) that is direct child of KateView and when I run it (e. g. Kate text editor), the list is shown across text edit border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way for a child to paint outside of a parent's QWidget rect, unfortunately. Your sibling approach is a popular solution to this problem. Another approach is for the child to notify the parent of what it wants to draw, but this can be a bit more advanced because you have to re-implement paint events.

Answer (score 0):

Today I found a possibly viable way -- it's based on `setWindowFlags(Qt::ToolTip)` method of QListWidget element. There's, however, some slight change in positioning and event handling.